# RenderFlex children having issue of unbounded height constraints

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am using the below code to create a list with childs.

```
 return ListView.separated(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Card(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              Flexible(
                fit: FlexFit.tight,
                flex: 1,
                child: ListTile(
                  leading: Image.asset( "/tray.png",width: 32.0,),
                  title: Text(packs[index]['name']),
                  trailing: IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.add,
                      color: Colors.yellow,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Flexible(
                fit: FlexFit.loose,
                flex: 1,
                child: ListView(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  children: <Widget>[],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
      separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(
        color: Colors.black,
      ),
      itemCount: packs.length,
    );
```

I get the below error. I have earlier many such issues in my other apps. But I could not get to solve this.

```
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.

RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#41bc7 relayoutBoundary=up11 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1691 pos 12: 'hasSize'
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Card file:///D:/apps/lib/tab_content.dart:49:16
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the Card widget has no size, indicated by the `hasSize` error. You could solve that by wrapping the Card widget with a Container or SizedBox widget and setting height and width properties on them or by wrapping the Card widget with an Expanded widget.
Here’s a quick video on what Expanded does: [Widget of the Week - Expanded](https://youtu.be/_rnZaagadyo)

EDIT: Checked the code in a Flutter project, but the error remains when you wrap the `Card` widget in an `Expanded` widget. So, use a `Container` or `SizedBox`, or any kind of widget where you can set the width and height explicitly.